# Getting Duplicate Entries when inserting a new record using mysqli in a php script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am writing a website and I have this code that normally should insert just one entry but in my case is duplicating the entries.

```php
    require_once 'login.php';
    $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) die("Fatal Error");

    $query  = "INSERT INTO cats(family, name, age) VALUES('Caracal', 'Panou', 4)";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) {
      die("Database access failed");
    }
```

Here is the code of login.php

```php
<?php
$hn = 'localhost';
$db = 'publications';
$un = 'sandro';
$pw = 'mypasswd';
?>
```

I don't use a form. I run the script just by refreshing the page.

Can somebody help to understand what is going on?

Thank you

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: It's worth checking your server logs to see if one request is made, or if two are actually made regardless of your intent.

Comment: @tadman OP => *"I run the script just by refreshing the page."*.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner That doesn't mean the browser isn't doing something funny. Some plugins can make it do things like load it, translate it by loading it again, etc.

Comment: @tadam Thank you for the tips. I want to focus on core PHP development. After I'm planning to move to frameworks like laravel or codeigniter.